# How do I find the intersection of two lists in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am using two lists as "sets" in Haskell, and I am supposed to find and return the intersection of the two lists. I have measures to remove the duplicates from the list however I cannot think of how to actually compare the lists and get another list that only contains the elements that are present in both the lists. Here is what I have so far

```
intersect :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
intersect [] _ = []
intersect _ [] = []
intersect (x:xs) L2 = filter (\x -> x 'elem' L2) L2
```

However, this is incorrect, but logically I cannot exactly think of how to make this work. Any ideas and suggestions will be appreciated! Also, it would be better if someone has any idea that doesn't involve importing any other modules as I want to depend on only the functions in the prelude for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use backtics to use a function as infix operator, so `` x `elem` L2 ``. Furthermore you here use `L2` twice (and since `L2` starts with an uppercase, the compiler will think that `L2` is a data constructor). You should filter one list with the items of the other list. `Integer` is a type and thus starts with an uppercase character.

If we thus fix the above problems, we obtain:

```
intersect :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
intersect [] _ = []
intersect _ [] = []
intersect xs ys = filter (\x -> x `elem` xs) ys
```

or shorter:

```
intersect :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
intersect [] = const []
intersect xs = filter (`elem` xs)
```

These however will *not* work on if `xs` is an infinite list and there is at least one item of `ys` that is not eventually produced for the `xs` list. One can use *diagonalization* to eventually yield all items that occur in both lists. One can use the [**`control-monad-omega`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-omega-0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Omega.html) for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggested edits and the help! I have corrected the grammatical errors in the code and I understand now what I should have done logically thanks to your explanation! :)

Comment: @user202004 if the answer is correct, please mark it as such